# WatchOS app got crashed by showing detail [WKRefreshBackgroundTask dealloc]

Tags: swift, watchos, apple-watch-complication, wkrefreshbackgroundtask

I know this crash is related to updating complication in background and system automatically release the object may be due to suspend state. So here is detail what I am trying to do in watchOS app.

I am updating complication content in background. This updated detail is received from server. so should I have to enable any background mode?

Provided background modes audio, Location, Remote notification and workout

But above mentioned mode did not match with my requirement as not using any above service and just updating complication data from server.

I am using scheduleBackgroundRefresh to update complication in every 15 min.

Here is crash log

```
 Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2054c564 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x20550d24 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100 (terminate_with_reason.c:102)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x20550cc0 abort_with_reason + 28 (terminate_with_reason.c:116)
3   WatchKit                        0x332b916c -[WKRefreshBackgroundTask dealloc] + 536 (SPUtils.h:15)
4   watchkitapp Extension           0x02f75710 outlined consume of Set<A>.Iterator._Variant<A> + 36
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x472552b8 _swift_release_dealloc + 28 (HeapObject.cpp:626)
6   watchkitapp Extension           0x02f757a0 partial apply for closure #1 in ExtensionDelegate.updateContentInBackgorund(_:) + 448416 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:74)
7   libswiftCore.dylib              0x472552b8 _swift_release_dealloc + 28 (HeapObject.cpp:626)
8   watchkitapp Extension           0x02f757a0 partial apply for closure #1 in ExtensionDelegate.updateContentInBackgorund(_:) + 448416 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:74)
9   watchkitapp Extension           0x02f75808 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Bool, @unowned Int?, @guaranteed DomainHome?, @guaranteed [String : Any]?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 448520 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  libswiftCore.dylib              0x472552b8 _swift_release_dealloc + 28 (HeapObject.cpp:626)
11  watchkitapp Extension           0x02f757a0 partial apply for closure #1 in ExtensionDelegate.updateContentInBackgorund(_:) + 448416 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:74)
12  watchkitapp Extension           0x02f7581c partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Bool, @unowned Int?, @guaranteed DomainHome?, @guaranteed [String : Any]?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 448540 (<compiler-generated>:0)
13  libswiftCore.dylib              0x472552b8 _swift_release_dealloc + 28 (HeapObject.cpp:626)
14  watchkitapp Extension           0x02f60c24 partial apply for specialized closure #1 in RequestManager.performRequestWithURL<A>(_:method:payload:useAuthentication:credentials:handler:) + 363556 (<compiler-generated>:0)
15  watchkitapp Extension           0x02f61b24 block_destroy_helper.85 + 16
16  libswiftCore.dylib              0x472552b8 _swift_release_dealloc + 28 (HeapObject.cpp:626)
17  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x2042ea5c _Block_release + 140 (runtime.cpp:177)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x20394fc0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x203a0e7c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 924 (inline_internal.h:2484)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2093ddcc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x20938df4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1852 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x209383b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
23  GraphicsServices                0x23ed8358 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2246)
24  UIKitCore                       0x3da4b87c UIApplicationMain + 1756 (UIApplication.m:4820)
25  libxpc.dylib                    0x20629bdc _xpc_objc_main.cold.3 + 208
26  libxpc.dylib                    0x20615c58 _xpc_objc_main + 212 (main.m:0)
27  libxpc.dylib                    0x2061823c xpc_main + 152 (init.c:1384)
28  Foundation                      0x213a1738 -[NSXPCListener resume] + 160 (NSXPCListener.m:276)
29  PlugInKit                       0x2a30c0a8 -[PKService run] + 396 (PKService.m:165)
30  WatchKit                        0x3329fe94 WKExtensionMain + 60 (main.m:19)
31  WatchKit                        0x3336d93c main + 12 (main.m:27)
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x203d0f48 start + 4
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. You also need to include the symbolicated crash log.

Comment: I think there is no need to add any background mode . I also matched my code with sample code provided in developer link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/creating_and_updating_complications

Comment: I receive similar crashes on my watch app. Apparently they are very rare and I cannot reproduce them in debug mode on the simulator or actual device.